# How to place multiple images at current location at MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have placed icon at current location. [pic-1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWtV5.png)
I want to place multiple images for current location like [pic-2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THr0F.png)

**1-** Required face icon at current location.

**2-** Required red circle around face icon with pulsating effect. If we zoom in /zoom out map then I need no movement in red circle. Red circle will always show around face icon with same size.

**3-** Required home icon at top (around 100 px above red circle) with same requirement as point 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any movement in circle on zoom in/out then you can make a '.png' of complete image like 'pic-2.png' and set it on current location.

Comment: Due to pulsating effect at red circle. I need different image.

Answer (score 0):

1. If first time and you enable request location the face icon will in center view. After that you can transfer the curent location to coordinates of view and movement if have any movement of curent location.
2. same 1
3. change image if need